# Column users_id is not unique

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Users(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    users = models.OneToOneField(Users, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Имя',max_length = 250)

class Info(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, blank=True, null=True)
    accountname = models.CharField('логин',max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, unique = True)
```

views.py

```
users = Users.objects.all()
for user in users:
    query = Person.objects.get(info__accountname=user)
    query.users = Users.objects.get(id=user.id)
    query.save()
```

В модели Person и Info данные загружаются из внешней базы. В модель Users загружаются из файла json, в данном случае нас интересует только поле name. В файле views мы перебираем всех пользователей и сравниваем с полем accountname. Если они равны то привязываем. Пользователи привязываются, но вместе с этим выскакивает ошибка:

```
column users_id is not unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то все запутанно и недостаточно данных.
Во-первых, вот эта строчка:

```
query.users = Users.objects.get(id=user.id)
```

Похоже правильнее так:

```
users = Users.objects.all()
for user in users:
    query = Person.objects.get(info__accountname=user)
    query.users = user
    query.save()
```

Давайте кое-что переименуем и упростим для ясности:

```
for users_item in Users.objects.all():
    person = Person.objects.get(info__accountname=users_item.name)
    person.users = users_item
    person.save()
```

Там, где вы расчитывали на неявное преобразование user к строке, лучше явно указать поле или сделать явное приведение типа.

Теперь с чем могла быть связана ваша ошибка.
В модели Users нет требования по уникальности поля name, а это значит, что может встретиться больше одной записи, которая будет сопоставляться с разными персонами.